# Streaming video file to YouTube Live with FFmpeg - Automatically resume after crash?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, youtube, live, rtmp

```
ffmpeg -re -i [FILENAME] -codec copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[STREAM KEY]
```

I'm able to use this command to stream a video file to YouTube Live without re-encoding. If FFmpeg crashes for some reason, how do I automatically resume streaming the video from where it left off?

Also, is there any GUI software that can do this? As far as I can tell, there is no passthrough option in OBS.

Comment: with the flag `-progress progress.txt` in ffmpeg you can track the progress of the video transformation.

Comment: @Nemesius Are you saying that the only way to resume FFmpeg where it left off is to use a script that reads from a progress file and runs FFmpeg again with `-ss [last out_time]`? I was hoping that FFmpeg had a built-in feature to do this.